# Docker-compose Angular app UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=200)

Tags: angular, docker

I'm using a docker-compose environment which contains 2 angular apps, both of which aren't running when I run `docker-compose up`.

I tried every fix like modifying COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT, restarting docker service, but nothing happens.

How can I solve this issue?

It seems to happen randomly. Sometimes restarting docker service fixes this, but sometimes it doesn't.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  # DB Django
  postgres:
    container_name: supv2_postgres
    image: infra_postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  # Real-time metrics retrieving database
  influxdb:
    container_name: supv2_influxdb
    image: infra_influxdb
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb
    environment:
      INFLUXDB_DB: metrics_collect
      INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER: user
      INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: userpass
    restart: always

  prometheus:
    container_name: supv2_prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus
    user: root
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ~/prometheus:/etc/prometheus/
      - ~/prometheus/prometheus_data:/prometheus

  report:
    image: report
    build: ./microservices/report
    container_name: report
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  
  portal:
    container_name: axians_portal
    build: ../../axians-portal/web-portal
    image: frontend
    volumes:
     - ../../axians-portal/web-portal:/app
     - /app/node_modules
    ports:
     - 4201:4200

  supfrontend:
    container_name: supv2_frontend
    build: ~/frontend_supv2/ngx-admin
    image: supv2_frontend
    volumes:
      - ~/frontend_supv2/ngx-admin:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 4301:4300

  #UI
  grafana:
    container_name: supv2_grafana
    image: infra_grafana
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    ports:
      - 4000:3000
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
    restart: always

  #Django orchestrator
  orchestrator:
    container_name: supv2_orchestrator
    image: infra_django
    build: ./Django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./microservices:/code/microservices
      - ./Django:/code
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

volumes:
  #persistent volume
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: can you provide docker-compose.yml to help you

Comment: I just edited my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may generate random behavior by sharing same node_modules in two different services in the same docker-compose, the randomness you observe may come from it.

```
...
portal:
  container_name: axians_portal
  build: ../../axians-portal/web-portal
  image: frontend
  volumes:
   - ../../axians-portal/web-portal:/app
   - /app/node_modules   # <-- shared node_modules
  ports:
   - 4201:4200

supfrontend:
  container_name: supv2_frontend
  build: ~/frontend_supv2/ngx-admin
  image: supv2_frontend
  volumes:
    - ~/frontend_supv2/ngx-admin:/app
    - /app/node_modules  # <-- shared node_modules
  ports:
    - 4301:4300
...
```

Try to have two different Host volume for node_modues, I know will take more place, but after your are to not have random behavior, when two process trying to write/read/process same files

Comment: In fact I specified the node_modules folder of both of my app with complete path, it npm build much faster now, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Vue/Quasar app running with docker compose on macOS. For me restarting Docker helped.